# How to map a one-to-many result to a Hibernate entity which is joined using a non-primary key?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Suppose there are two classes, Manager and Engineer. Conceptually, an engineer can belong to only one manager and a manager can have multiple engineers but schematically they can be linked by the department id. However, there are no foreign key association between the classes.

```
public class Manager {
   .....
   private Long deptId; 
 } 

public class Engineer {
   .....
   private Long deptId; 
 }
```

The following query works in mySQL:

`select * from manager m left join engineer e on m.dept_id = e.dept_id.`

It returns multiple rows corresponding to the different employees sharing the same department as the manager. I'm not able to map the result of this query to the entities. I would like to do something like the following:

```
public class Manager {
   .....
   private Long deptId; 

   @OnetoMany
   private List<Engineer> engineers;
 }
```

`@ManytoOne` and `@OnetoMany` annotations expect a foreign key to use for mapping so the above isn't working. Are there other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `@JoinColumn` manually. Check out [this article](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-model-association-dont-reference-primary-key-columns/) for details